# Delete link Not Working

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, mysqli

Can someone figure out why my 'delete' link is not working?
This is the code for currentout.php which has a delete link

```
 <?Php
    require "config.php";           

    $page_name="currentout.php";  
    $start=$_GET['start'];
    if(strlen($start) > 0 and !is_numeric($start)){
    echo "Data Error";
    exit;
    }


    $eu = ($start - 0); 
    $limit = 10;                                 
    $this1 = $eu + $limit; 
    $back = $eu - $limit; 
    $next = $eu + $limit; 

    $nume = $dbo->query("select count(id) from receipt")->fetchColumn();


    echo "<TABLE class='t1'>";
    echo  "<tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Pass</th><th>Amount</th><th>Action</th></tr>";


    $query=" SELECT * FROM receipt  limit $eu, $limit ";


    foreach ($dbo->query($query) as $row) {

    @$m=$i%2;
    @$i=$i+1;   
    echo "<tr class='r$m'><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[phone_num]</td><td>$row[Amount]</td><td><a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a></td></tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";

    if($nume > $limit ){ 
    echo "<table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='30%'>";

    if($back >=0) { 
    print "<a href='$page_name?start=$back'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>PREV</font></a>"; 
    } 

    echo "</td><td align=center width='30%'>";
    $i=0;
    $l=1;
    for($i=0;$i < $nume;$i=$i+$limit){
    if($i <> $eu){
    echo " <a href='$page_name?start=$i'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>$l</font></a> ";
    }
    else { echo "<font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>$l</font>";}        
    $l=$l+1;
    }


    echo "</td><td  align='right' width='30%'>";

    if($this1 < $nume) { 
    print "<a href='$page_name?start=$next'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a>";} 
    echo "</td></tr></table>";

    } 
    ?>
```

and this is my delete.php

```
<?php
$sql = "DELETE FROM receipt  WHERE ID=  :ID";
$stmt = $pdo->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindParam(':ID', $_GET['id'), PDO::PARAM_INT);  
$stmt->execute();
header('location: index.php');
?>
```

I need the user to be able to delete an entry when they click on the 'delete' link.

Edit. This is the HTML output

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
body {
    background-image: ;
    background-color: #F0F0F0;
}
.style1 {
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
.style2 {
    font-size: 24px;
    font-weight: bold;
}
-->
</style>
<link href="../styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.style3 {font-size: 18px}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>


   <p>&nbsp;</p>

   <table width="781" height="48" border="0" align="center">
     <tr>
       <td><h3 align="right"> <a href="logout.php">Logout</a> </h3></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
       <td><h3 align="left"> <span class="usrname">admin </span> </h3></td>
     </tr>
   </table>
   <table width="781" height="48" border="0" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td width="186"><a href="../receipt/receiptt.php">Book  New</a> </td>
      <td width="152"><a href="../current in/currentIn.php">Current in </a></td>
      <td width="34"><div align="center"><a href="../out/currentout.php"></a> </div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
   <table width="781" height="190" align="center">
    <tr>
      <td height="61" colspan="4"><div align="center" class="style2 style3">CHECK OUT </div>
        <span class="style1">There are currently  tourists in the park </span></td>
    </tr>



<br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: start in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\table\out\currentout.php</b> on line <b>73</b><br />
<TABLE class='t1'><tr><th>ID</th><th>Name</th><th>Class</th><th>Mark</th><th>Action</th><th>Action</th><th>Action</th></tr><br />
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined variable: row in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\table\out\currentout.php</b> on line <b>98</b><br />
<tr class='r0'><td>10</td><td>Sam</td><td>478562</td><td>450</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r1'><td>9</td><td>Jim Jones</td><td>72548623</td><td>900</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r0'><td>6</td><td>   Jane C.P.L</td><td>64849</td><td>560</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r1'><td>7</td><td> maryanne</td><td>31356664</td><td>1400</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r0'><td>8</td><td> Jim Okoth</td><td>1028587</td><td>1000</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r1'><td>11</td><td>joe</td><td>554</td><td>48</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r0'><td>12</td><td>john mugambi</td><td>725485632</td><td>400</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r1'><td>13</td><td>ryan</td><td>1558</td><td>200</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r0'><td>14</td><td>James </td><td>5563</td><td>500</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr><tr class='r1'><td>15</td><td>mike</td><td>2584</td><td>45</td><td><a href='delete.php?id='>delete</a></td></tr></table><table align = 'center' width='50%'><tr><td  align='left' width='30%'></td><td align=center width='30%'><font face='Verdana' size='4' color=red>1</font> <a href='currentout.php?start=10'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>2</font></a>  <a href='currentout.php?start=20'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>3</font></a> </td><td  align='right' width='30%'><a href='currentout.php?start=10'><font face='Verdana' size='2'>NEXT</font></a></td></tr></table>   


  <p align='center'><a href='../login/usermenu.php'><strong>Home  </strong></a></p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is your form or link?

Comment: @wayzz edited it..can have a look at line 37

Comment: Have you checked if `id` is passed to that delete page?

Comment: id isn't being passed to the delete page

Comment: what is $row['id'] displaying in the foreach?

Comment: @wayzz displays the returned records in side the rows of the table

Comment: but is $row['id'] being displayed?

Comment: yea, it is displayed and all the records in the databasen are returned

Answer (score 2):

change the following line

```
echo "<tr class='r$m'><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[phone_num]</td><td>$row[Amount]</td><td><a href='delete.php?id=$id'>delete</a></td></tr>";
```

to

```
echo "<tr class='r$m'><td>$row[id]</td><td>$row[name]</td><td>$row[phone_num]</td><td>$row[Amount]</td><td><a href='delete.php?id=$row[id]>delete</a></td></tr>";
```

Please note that the code you are using to delete a row in the database is very unsafe. everyone can go to delete.php?id=1 and delete row 1

Comment: id isn't being passed to the delete page and the code outputs all the data in a single erow

Comment: can you please provide the source code of your html output?

Comment: the currentout.php outputs the database records

Comment: what is the html of the link <a href='delete.php?id=$row['id']'>delete</a>?

Comment: I'm not getting you, the url <a href='delete.php?id=$row['id']'>delete</a> links to delete.php of which i have provided the code

Comment: yes but what is the full link in html after it is echoed? is the link correct or broken?

Comment: When i click on delete i get this error     Fatal error: Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object in      the link in the browser is http://localhost/table/out/delete.php?id=

Comment: Your link is broken 'id='. Variable id has no value when clicking on link. This is your problem.

Comment: Please run your code in the browser like you normally do, right click and choose 'show source'. Please copy the source code and paste it as an edit to your question

Comment: you are not using the start paremeter, that is why the query fails. Please use currentout.php?start=0